# csv to php - Select specific row based on the value of the first column

Tags: php, loops, csv

I'm using an external .csv file to extrapolate some values in php and do calculations. My .csv is structured in the following way (this is a very simple example, my csv usually has 50/60 rows everyone with a different name):

> Sales,10,24,56
>  Revenues,14,71,105

I would like to use a php instruction to select only the row named "Revenues" or only that named "Sales". Until now I've used a "for" loop but that is based only on a i++ variable.

```
$csv = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('csv/sample.csv'));    

for ($i = 12, $k=$i+11; $i < $k; $i++) {
            echo '<td>';
            echo number_format($csv[$i],0,'.',',');
            echo '</td>';
        }
echo '</tr>';
```

If "sales" and "revenues" have a different position I'm not able to call the right values.

UPDATE:

Here it is the print_r($csv)

```
Array
(
    [0] => USD in millions.
    [1] => 2005-09
    [2] => 2006-09
    [3] => 2007-09
    [4] => 2008-09
    [5] => 2009-09
    [6] => 2010-09
    [7] => 2011-09
    [8] => 2012-09
    [9] => 2013-09
    [10] => 2014-09
    [11] => TTM
Revenue
    [12] => 13931
    [13] => 19315
    [14] => 24006
    [15] => 32479
    [16] => 42905
    [17] => 65225
    [18] => 108249
    [19] => 156508
    [20] => 170910
    [21] => 182795
    [22] => 199800
Cost of revenue
    [23] => 9888
    [24] => 13717
    [25] => 15852
    [26] => 21334
    [27] => 25683
    [28] => 39541
    [29] => 64431
    [30] => 87846
    [31] => 106606
    [32] => 112258
    [33] => 121368
Gross profit
    [34] => 4043
    [35] => 5598
    [36] => 8154
    [37] => 11145
    [38] => 17222
    [39] => 25684
    [40] => 43818
    [41] => 68662
    [42] => 64304
    [43] => 70537
    [44] => 78432
Operating expenses
Research and development
    [45] => 534
    [46] => 712
    [47] => 782
    [48] => 1109
    [49] => 1333
    [50] => 1782
    [51] => 2429
    [52] => 3381
    [53] => 4475
    [54] => 6041
    [55] => 6606
Sales
    [56] =>  General and administrative
    [57] => 1859
    [58] => 2433
    [59] => 2963
    [60] => 3761
    [61] => 4149
    [62] => 5517
    [63] => 7599
    [64] => 10040
    [65] => 10830
    [66] => 11993
    [67] => 12540
Total operating expenses
    [68] => 2393
    [69] => 3145
    [70] => 3745
    [71] => 4870
    [72] => 5482
    [73] => 7299
    [74] => 10028
    [75] => 13421
    [76] => 15305
    [77] => 18034
    [78] => 19146
Operating income
    [79] => 1650
    [80] => 2453
    [81] => 4409
    [82] => 6275
    [83] => 11740
    [84] => 18385
    [85] => 33790
    [86] => 55241
    [87] => 48999
    [88] => 52503
    [89] => 59286
Interest Expense
    [90] => 
    [91] => 
    [92] => 
    [93] => 
    [94] => 
    [95] => 
    [96] => 
    [97] => 
    [98] => 136
    [99] => 384
    [100] => 431
Other income (expense)
    [101] => 165
    [102] => 365
    [103] => 599
    [104] => 620
    [105] => 326
    [106] => 155
    [107] => 415
    [108] => 522
    [109] => 1292
    [110] => 1364
    [111] => 1335
Income before taxes
    [112] => 1815
    [113] => 2818
    [114] => 5008
    [115] => 6895
    [116] => 12066
    [117] => 18540
    [118] => 34205
    [119] => 55763
    [120] => 50155
    [121] => 53483
    [122] => 60190
Provision for income taxes
    [123] => 480
    [124] => 829
    [125] => 1512
    [126] => 2061
    [127] => 3831
    [128] => 4527
    [129] => 8283
    [130] => 14030
    [131] => 13118
    [132] => 13973
    [133] => 15728
Net income from continuing operations
    [134] => 1335
    [135] => 1989
    [136] => 3496
    [137] => 4834
    [138] => 8235
    [139] => 14013
    [140] => 25922
    [141] => 41733
    [142] => 37037
    [143] => 39510
    [144] => 44462
Net income
    [145] => 1335
    [146] => 1989
    [147] => 3496
    [148] => 4834
    [149] => 8235
    [150] => 14013
    [151] => 25922
    [152] => 41733
    [153] => 37037
    [154] => 39510
    [155] => 44462
Net income available to common shareholders
    [156] => 1335
    [157] => 1989
    [158] => 3496
    [159] => 4834
    [160] => 8235
    [161] => 14013
    [162] => 25922
    [163] => 41733
    [164] => 37037
    [165] => 39510
    [166] => 44462
Earnings per share
Basic
    [167] => 0.24
    [168] => 0.34
    [169] => 0.58
    [170] => 0.78
    [171] => 1.32
    [172] => 2.20
    [173] => 4.01
    [174] => 6.38
    [175] => 5.72
    [176] => 6.49
    [177] => 7.44
Diluted
    [178] => 0.22
    [179] => 0.32
    [180] => 0.56
    [181] => 0.77
    [182] => 1.30
    [183] => 2.16
    [184] => 3.95
    [185] => 6.31
    [186] => 5.68
    [187] => 6.45
    [188] => 7.39
Weighted average shares outstanding
Basic
    [189] => 5659
    [190] => 5908
    [191] => 6052
    [192] => 6171
    [193] => 6251
    [194] => 6366
    [195] => 6470
    [196] => 6544
    [197] => 6477
    [198] => 6086
    [199] => 5978
Diluted
    [200] => 5997
    [201] => 6143
    [202] => 6225
    [203] => 6315
    [204] => 6349
    [205] => 6473
    [206] => 6557
    [207] => 6617
    [208] => 6522
    [209] => 6123
    [210] => 6016
EBITDA
    [211] => 1829
    [212] => 2678
    [213] => 4726
    [214] => 6748
    [215] => 12474
    [216] => 19412
    [217] => 35604
    [218] => 58518
    [219] => 57048
    [220] => 61813
    [221] => 68998
)
```

Comment: SO, get first value of row and check if it is `sales`.

Comment: Where's your attempted code?

Comment: @u_mulder Hi, do you suggest to apply an if? How should I structure the for loop inside if? Thanks for your reply

Comment: @aldrin27 I've updated the first post. Thanks for your reply

Comment: what is the contents of `csv[$i]`?

Comment: Your for loop is wrong.

Comment: @u_mulder The content is given by "$csv = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('csv/sample.csv'));" and the content of sample.csv has the same structure of "Sales" and "Revenues" that you can see in the first post

Comment: @aldrin27 Yes, I know that for what I'm asking the for-loop is not correct. I really don't know how to select just the row based on the value of the first element of the row.

Comment: I know how content is received. I  want to know the value of `$csv[$i]`

Comment: What is `$k`? may i know that? and can you `print_r($csv);`?

Comment: @u_mulder The value is, for example -> $csv[1] = Sales, $csv[2]=10, $csv[6]=14, and so on...

Comment: Read your file line by line with `fgetcsv`. And check if first element of line is `sales`

Comment: Guys, I've attached the print_r($csv)...see the first post

Answer (score 0):

First use [**`preg_grep`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) & [**`file`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) with [**`str_getcsv`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to solve your problem.

First `$file = file('csv/sample.csv');`

then `$revenues  = preg_grep ('/^Revenues/i', $file);`

then

```
for ($revenues as $revenue)
{
    $revenue = str_getcsv($revenue);
    echo $revenue[0] . $revenue[1] . $revenue[2] . $revenue[3];//Revenue key 0,1,2,3
}
```

then `$sales  = preg_grep ('/^Sales/i', $file);`

then

```
for ($sales as $sale)
{
    $sale = str_getcsv($sale);
    echo $sale[0] . $sale[1] . $sale[2] . $sale[3];//Sale key 0,1,2,3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the csv into a named key array and then refer to the relevant row entry by name.

```
$csv = array();
$file = new SplFileObject( "csv/sample.csv" );
$file->setFlags( SplFileObject::READ_CSV );
foreach( $file as $index => $row ) {
    $csv[ strtolower( $row[0] )]=array_splice( $row, 1, count( $row ) );
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($csv['sales'],true),'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sales = [];
$revenues = [];
foreach($csv as $key => $val)
{
  $sales[] = $val['Sales'];
  $revenues[] $val['Revenue'];
}
 print_r($sales);
 print_r($revenues);
```

If you wish to get all data's:

```
 $data = [];
foreach($csv as $key => $val)
{
 $data[] = ['Sales' => $val['Sales'], 'Revenue' => $val['Revenue'], ......]; // so on and so forth.
}
print_r($data);
```